# Parse xml file with python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have this simple xml file:

```
<BSB>
    <APPLSUMMARY>
        <MAIN W="S1" X="{ND}"/>
        <COUNTS Z="0" AB="0" BB="0" CB="0" DB="0" EB="0" FB="0" GB="{ND}"/>
        <SCOTDEBT OQB="{ND}"/>
        <NOTICES HB="0" IB="3"/>
        <SUB_BLOCKS C="3" D="3" E="1" F="0"/>
        <ALIAS_NO UPB="0" VPB="{ND}" WPB="0"/>
        <ASSOC_NO DD="0" ED="0" AC="0"/>
        <ALERTSUMM PB="0" QB="0" RB="{ND}" SB="{ND}" TB="{ND}" UB="{ND}"/>
        <HHOSUMM BC="{ND}" RGB="{ND}"/>
        <TPD INB="{ND}" JNB="{ND}" KNB="{ND}" LNB="{ND}"/>
        <OCCUPANCY AD="1"/>
        <DECEASED LQB="1" FCC="{ND}" GCC="{ND}" HCC="{ND}" ICC="{ND}"/>
        <IMPAIRED MQB="0"/>
        <ACTIVITY JCC="{ND}" KCC="{ND}" LCC="{ND}"/>
        <ADVERSE MCC="{ND}" HHC="{ND}"/>
    </APPLSUMMARY>
</BSB>
```

I want to create in python a csv file that contains only the DECEASED contents in columns like this:

[image]

So, I am trying to get the values of the DECEASED bit and align them in columns.

I have tried this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import io
parsed = objectify.parse(open(path)) // path is where the xml file is saved
root = parsed.getroot()
data = []



for elt in root.BSB.DECEASED:

    el_data = {}
    for child in elt.getchildren():
        el_data[child.tag] = child.text
        data.append(el_data)
    perf =pd.DataFrame(data).drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep='first', inplace=False)
    
    print(perf)
    perf.to_csv('DECESEAD.csv')
```

I get an empty dataset:

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []

Can anyone help me get the values inside the DECEASED tag, please?

Comment: Could this be a typo: `root.BSB.DECEASED`?  Just looking at the XML it seems this should be `root.BSB.APPLSUMMARY.DECEASED` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below collects the data you are looking for

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from typing import Dict

xml = '''<BSB>
    <APPLSUMMARY>
        <MAIN W="S1" X="{ND}"/>
        <COUNTS Z="0" AB="0" BB="0" CB="0" DB="0" EB="0" FB="0" GB="{ND}"/>
        <SCOTDEBT OQB="{ND}"/>
        <NOTICES HB="0" IB="3"/>
        <SUB_BLOCKS C="3" D="3" E="1" F="0"/>
        <ALIAS_NO UPB="0" VPB="{ND}" WPB="0"/>
        <ASSOC_NO DD="0" ED="0" AC="0"/>
        <ALERTSUMM PB="0" QB="0" RB="{ND}" SB="{ND}" TB="{ND}" UB="{ND}"/>
        <HHOSUMM BC="{ND}" RGB="{ND}"/>
        <TPD INB="{ND}" JNB="{ND}" KNB="{ND}" LNB="{ND}"/>
        <OCCUPANCY AD="1"/>
        <DECEASED LQB="1" FCC="{ND}" GCC="{ND}" HCC="{ND}" ICC="{ND}"/>
        <IMPAIRED MQB="0"/>
        <ACTIVITY JCC="{ND}" KCC="{ND}" LCC="{ND}"/>
        <ADVERSE MCC="{ND}" HHC="{ND}"/>
    </APPLSUMMARY>
</BSB>'''


def _clean_dict(attributes: Dict) -> Dict:
    result = {}
    for k, v in attributes.items():
        if v[0] == '{':
            val = v[1:-1]
        else:
            val = v
        result[k] = val
    return result


data = []
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for d in root.findall('.//DECEASED'):
    data.append(_clean_dict(d.attrib))
print(data)
```

output (list of dicts)

```
[{'LQB': '1', 'FCC': 'ND', 'GCC': 'ND', 'HCC': 'ND', 'ICC': 'ND'}]
```